# Odoo 14 Error: connection to database failed and password authentication failed for user

Tags: python, odoo, pgadmin-4, odoo-14

Hello I am trying to open odoo using the localhost:8069,it gives me the following errors

```
   2021-08-08 23:50:56,897 7896 INFO ? odoo: Odoo version 14.0 
    2021-08-08 23:50:56,897 7896 INFO ? odoo: Using configuration file at C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\odoo\debian\odoo.conf 
    2021-08-08 23:50:56,897 7896 INFO ? odoo: addons paths: ['C:\\Users\\xxx\\Desktop\\odoo\\odoo\\addons', 'c:\\users\\xxx\\appdata\\local\\openerp s.a\\odoo\\addons\\14.0', 'c:\\users\\lenovo\\desktop\\odoo\\addons', 'c:\\users\\xxx\\desktop\\odoo\\odoo\\addons'] 
    2021-08-08 23:50:56,897 7896 INFO ? odoo: database: odoo@localhost:5432 
    2021-08-08 23:50:57,070 7896 INFO ? odoo.addons.base.models.ir_actions_report: You need Wkhtmltopdf to print a pdf version of the reports. 
    2021-08-08 23:50:57,207 7896 INFO ? odoo.service.server: HTTP service (werkzeug) running on xxx:8069 
    2021-08-08 23:51:16,129 7896 INFO ? odoo.http: HTTP Configuring static files 
    2021-08-08 23:51:16,209 7896 INFO ? odoo.sql_db: Connection to the database failed 
    2021-08-08 23:51:16,217 7896 INFO ? werkzeug: 10.5.53.253 - - [08/Aug/2021 23:51:16] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 - 0 0.000 0.072
    2021-08-08 23:51:16,232 7896 ERROR ? werkzeug: Error on request:
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
psycopg2.OperationalError: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "odoo" - - -
```

[image: This is the page I get]
I am following the odoo documentation to install, setup, and use odoo.
How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

This error is due to the fact that you did not provide password for the postgres user for connecting to the db.
In odoo conf

```
db_port = 5432
db_user = odoo
db_password = pwd
```

change pwd to the password for the odoo user

Comment: hi, I already have a password provided. `[options]
; This is the password that allows database operations:
; admin_passwd = admin
db_host = localhost
db_port = 5432
db_user = odoo
db_password = odoo
;xmlrpc_port = 8069
addons_path = C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\odoo\addons`

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to create new role in postgresql and give grant access https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/sql-grant.html

[image]